# Reference needed for neural networks finding solutions of PDE's

Tags: neural-networks, reference-request

[DL-PDE](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.04463) prescribes a way to feed a neural network data, which in turn comes up with a PDE of the form

$$u_{t}(t,x,y) = F(x,y,u,u_{x},u_{y},u_{xx},u_{xy},u_{yy},...) \hspace{0.5cm} (x,y) \in \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}, t \in [0, T]$$

I am looking for a way to feed a neural network the same data and also prescribe a number of other variables (say 2, making the total number of variables 3), and the neural network could come up with a system of PDE's comprising of three equations with three variables.

Any leads for this?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange. You inserted an image containing an equation. If you are comfortable in keeping the equation using LaTex then please do it.